# Calculating the probability of a string

Tags: java, string, probability, n-gram

I want to calculate the probability of characters occurring in a string. For example given a string "test", I want to get P(test).

```
P(test) = p(t) * p(e|t) * p (s|te) * p(t|es)
```

I have calculated the various bi-gram frequencies of more than 100k strings and calculated the probabilities of their occurrence. My question is, by just multiplying the probabilities of n-grams in a string will I get an accurate answer or is there a better away for finding the same?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `p(s|te)` and `p(t|tes)`?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik No. It should be `p(t|es)`. I want to find the probability of a word based on its bi-grams. Hence I want to find the probability of occurrence of a character given a bi-gram.

Comment: But then, clearly, the whole equation cannot be correct. `p(test)` is not equal to the product of bigram probabilities. Is that why you put a capital `P(test)` there? Since you take into account that it is not the exact probability of the appearance of the word "test"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bi-grams, your answer will be as accurate as you can get with a [second-order Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Variations). The results are surprisingly good for such a simple model, but of course you can do even better with more expressive models. For instance, in language modeling, [Hidden Markov Models (HMMs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) are very often used.

Comment: Thanks HMM was the thing I was looking for. :)